# How do I proceed if I cannot make sense of the reason to close the question?

Tags: support, questions, closed-questions

I'm new to Drupal, but reasonably experienced with stackoverflow.

I have a very specific question ([change font size for displayed code](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/202612)), namely how to change Drupal configuration to achieve a specific change in the appearance of a Drupal-generated web page.

My question is put on hold for being "too broad": "There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format."

I cannot make sense of this.

Case 1, too many possible answers - neither probable, nor possibly a problem. I will accept the first answer that works. Why does it matter whether a certain change of appearance can be achieved in one, few, or many different ways?

Case 2, good answer would be too long - sorry, if such a simple change of appearance requires an exceedingly long instruction, then Drupal must be a very poor content management system. I cannot believe that a volunteer moderator at this site, almost certainly a Drupal enthusiast, really means that.

Comment: _if such a simple change of appearance requires an exceedingly long instruction, then Drupal must be a very poor content management system_ That wouldn't make a difference to a question being on or off topic of course, and I doubt if it were true that it would affect someone's decision to be a moderator or not...but I do agree "too broad" perhaps doesn't fit in this case. The question could be clarified a bit though, I've left a comment - hopefully that'll push it towards re-opening or at least get you going in the right direction

Comment: The first revision was simply "How to change the font size for displayed code? Specifically, a Python script, displayed using SyntaxHighlighter. According to Firebug analysis no css is active. So I have no clue where to search for something configurable." Apart the fact it's not true no CSS is active, that question is like asking "I am trying to make a cheesecake New York style, but it doesn't come out good, and I don't know what I do anything wrong." The question was edited after it was closed.

Comment: Without even knowing which modules, if any, are installed, how can we say which CSS are used? The OP even says there aren't active CSS.

Comment: Also, the problem of too many possible answers is not yours, but of Stack Exchange. The closing reason applies to all the Stack Exchange sites, which means every site has that closing reason, which also means Stack Exchange doesn't want such open-ended questions.

Comment: Kiamlaluno, a comment like "It cannot be that no CSS is active. Don't trust Firebug, analyse using XXX" would have been helpful. Closing the question with reasons that were not meant to be taken literally was extremely unhelpful. Hadn't I had so many good experiences with Stackoverflow in the past, you would have turned me away from this site.